# Error: "Array to string conversion" - Implode Function

Tags: php

**The Script:**

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $some_text_1 = $_POST['some_text_1'];
    $some_text_2 = $_POST['some_text_2'];
    $some_text_3 = $_POST['some_text_3'];

    $myarray = array($some_text_1, $some_text_2, $some_text_3);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($myarray); $i++) {

        $tqs = "INSERT INTO `table` (`some_text`) VALUES ('" . $myarray[$i] . "')";
        $tqr = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));


        $tqs = "SELECT `id` FROM `table`  WHERE `some_text` = '" . $myarray[$i] . "'";
        $tqr = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
        $fetch_array[] = mysqli_fetch_array($tqr);

    }

    $fetch_array = implode(", ", $fetch_array);

?>
```

I am looking to insert the array into a row of a column like in this following example:

```
the_row: | 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

Though when using the implode function I am getting this error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in ... (points to the implode function)
```

Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array` returns an array – so in `$fetch_array` you have an _array of arrays_, and that’s what `implode` is complaining about. If you only need one column value from each row, then put only that value into `$fetch_array` as a new element in each loop iteration.

Comment: You should read up on sql injection and prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) requires an array of strings as the second parameter. You are giving it an array of arrays.

You could use something like this to solve that (just an example):

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($tqr);
$fetch_array[] = row['id'];
```